# How do I make setState run from Class ? flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to use a command in class other
Example

I need to use a command in class other
Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class SelectionUser {

  BuildContext _context;
  var _pagy;

  int n = 0;


  open(int x) {
    n = x * 10;
    setState(() {}); //////////////////////////////
  }


  SelectionUser(this._context, this._pagy);
}
```

Comment: you can have a look state management approaches. https://pub.dev/packages/get

Comment: You could just retuen the value `n` in `open()` and do the `setState()` in your widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `VoidCallback` parameter to your class like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends State<...>{

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    final user = SelectionUser(() => setState((){}), null)
  }

  ...
}


class SelectionUser {
  SelectionUser(this._setState, this._pagy);
  var _pagy;
  VoidCallback _setState;

  int n = 0;


  open(int x) {
    n = x * 10;
    _setState(); //////////////////////////////
  }
}
```

Then your `user.open()` will call the `_setState` callback that triggers the `setState` as required

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need a `BuildContext` in your class and you want to call `setState` makes it obvious that you should not have a simple class, but instead inherit from `StatefulWidget` and `State<>`.

More information on how to do so can be found [in the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).